# Resolve ambiguity resulting from multiple inheritance of classes which share a common template class

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance, ambiguous, diamond-problem

I am trying to create a base class which is a template class and accepts, as a templace, some class. This base class in the parent class of two other classes which are themselves the parents of the final class. Thus, I have the traditional diamond problem in c++ with the addition that the root base class is a template class. Using virtual inheritance here does not quite do the trick.

Edit: Included some code (and corrected typos)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

template<class TemplateT>
class MainMaster {
    protected: 
        std::string name;
        int number;
        TemplateT variableProp;

    public:
        explicit MainMaster(std::string, int);

        void setName(std::string);
        std::string getName();
        void printName();

        void setNumber(int);
        int getNumber();
        void printNumber();

        void printMasterProperties(std::string);

        void setVarProp(TemplateT);
        TemplateT getVarProp();
};    

template<class TemplateT>
MainMaster<TemplateT>::MainMaster(std::string nameIn, int numIn){
    setName(nameIn);
    setNumber(numIn);
}    

template<class TemplateT>
void MainMaster<TemplateT>::setName(std::string nameIn){ name = nameIn; }

template<class TemplateT>
std::string MainMaster<TemplateT>::getName(){ return name; }

template<class TemplateT>
void MainMaster<TemplateT>::printName(){ cout << "Master's name is " << name << endl; }

template<class TemplateT>
void MainMaster<TemplateT>::setNumber(int numIn){ number = numIn; }

template<class TemplateT>
int MainMaster<TemplateT>::getNumber(){ return number; }

template<class TemplateT>
void MainMaster<TemplateT>::printNumber(){ cout << name << "'s number is " << number << endl; }

template<class TemplateT>
void MainMaster<TemplateT>::printMasterProperties(std::string pre = ""){
    cout << pre << "Master Properties" << endl
        << pre << "-Number: " << number << endl;
}

class ChildOne: public virtual MainMaster<std::string>{
    protected:
        std::string propOne;

    public:
//      using MainMaster::MainMaster;
        ChildOne(std::string nameIn, int numIn, std::string p1);
        void printName();
        void setPropOne(std::string);
        std::string getPropOne();

        void printOnesProps(std::string);
};    

ChildOne::ChildOne(std::string nameIn, int numIn, std::string p1): MainMaster<std::string>(nameIn,numIn){
    setPropOne(p1);
}

void ChildOne::printName(){ cout << "ChildOne's name is " << name << endl; }

void ChildOne::setPropOne(std::string propIn){ propOne = propIn; }

std::string ChildOne::getPropOne(){ return propOne; }

void ChildOne::printOnesProps(std::string pre = ""){
    printMasterProperties("-");
    cout << pre << "One Properties" << endl
        << pre << "-PropOne: " << propOne << endl;
}    

class ChildTwo: public virtual MainMaster<int>{
    protected:
        std::string propTwo;

    public:
        ChildTwo(std::string nameIn, int numIn, std::string p2);
        void printName();

        void setPropTwo(std::string);
        std::string getPropTwo();

        void printTwosProps(std::string);
};

ChildTwo::ChildTwo(std::string nameIn, int numIn, std::string p2): MainMaster<int>(nameIn,numIn){
    setPropTwo(p2);
}

void ChildTwo::printName(){
    cout << "ChidTwo's name is " << name << endl;
}

void ChildTwo::setPropTwo(std::string propIn){ propTwo = propIn; }

std::string ChildTwo::getPropTwo(){ return propTwo; }

void ChildTwo::printTwosProps(std::string pre = ""){
    printMasterProperties("-");
    cout << pre << "Two Properties" << endl
        << pre << "-PropTwo: " << propTwo << endl;
}

class FinalChild: public ChildOne, public ChildTwo{
    protected:
        double finalProp;

    public:
        FinalChild(std::string nameIn, int num, std::string prop1 ,std::string prop2, double pFinal);
        void printFinalProps(std::string);
};

FinalChild::FinalChild(std::string nameIn, int num, std::string prop1 ,std::string prop2, double pFinal):
ChildOne(nameIn, num, prop1),
ChildTwo(nameIn, num, prop2),
MainMaster(nameIn, num){
    finalProp = pFinal; 
}

void FinalChild::printFinalProps(std::string pre = ""){
    printMasterProperties("-");
    cout << pre << name << "'s Final Properties" << endl;
    cout << pre << "-Number: " << number << endl;
    cout << pre << "-PropOne: " << propOne << endl;
    cout << pre << "-PropTwo: " << propTwo << endl;
    cout << pre << "-finalProp " << finalProp << endl;
}

int main () {
    MainMaster<char> master("Master", 0);
    ChildOne child1("Child1",1,"P1One");
    ChildTwo child2("Child2",2,"P2Two");
    FinalChild finalC("FinalChild", 3, "P1Final", "P2Final", 3.0);

    master.printMasterProperties();
    child1.printOnesProps();
    child2.printTwosProps();
    finalC.printFinalProps();


}
```

Comment: Show an example of your problem, what exactly  and how have you tried it?

Comment: An instantiation of a template is a class, just like any other. This has nothing to do with whatever problem it is that you're having.

Comment: If it has nothing to do with the problem why is it that if, in the above code, you make MainMaster no longer a template class the code works? I initially thought the same thing, but it appears that with each new instantiation of the template class a new kind of class with the appropriate parameter is made which leads to ambiguity.

Comment: `MainMaster<int>` and `MainMaster<string>` are two different classes (instantiated from the same class template, but that's inconsequential). There's no diamond, virtual inheritance does nothing in your case except making life more complicated. You need to disambiguate stuff manually, or rethink your design.

Comment: How does virtual inheritance do nothing? If you remove the template aspects of MainMaster and then compile the code it runs ONLY with the virtual inheritance.

Comment: If you remove the template aspects of MainMaster you will end up with *one* class, which is different from *two different* classes.

Comment: Okay, so I have tried to disambiguate by changing the references using this. this:: and ChildOne:: to no avail. Can  you perhaps give me example of one of the ambiguous references as to how to eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: Disambiguate by scoping with base class name, e.g. `MainMaster<int>::`. Better yet, use containment, not inheritance.

Comment: The above code is an example of a problem I am having in a larger code project. I may write a post about my project design in general, but the purpose of this question you've helped me solve it, thank you.